# Python error for my table

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
t={"Items":[{"AssetId":1609391663,"Name":"Green Checkered Lamp shade","AbsoluteUrl":"https://www.roblox.com/catalog/1609391663/Green-Checkered-Lamp-shade","Price":20,"BestPrice":null,"Remaining":null,"HasSecondaryInfo":false,"NoPriceText":null,"IsFree":false,"Creator":null,"AssetRestrictionIcon":{"TooltipText":null,"CssTag":null,"LoadAssetRestrictionIconCss":true,"HasTooltip":false},"AssetStatusIcon":{"CssTag":"sale","DisplayText":"New","ShowTimerIcon":true},"Thumbnail":{"Final":true,"Url":"https://t0.rbxcdn.com/9fbc2414f0f615cd69ac5b8438861eaa","RetryUrl":"","IsApproved":true}},{"AssetId":1587175771,"Name":"Overseer Wings of Terror","AbsoluteUrl":"https://www.roblox.com/catalog/1587175771/Overseer-Wings-of-Terror","Price":20000,"BestPrice":null,"Remaining":275,"HasSecondaryInfo":true,"NoPriceText":null,"IsFree":false,"Creator":null,"AssetRestrictionIcon":{"TooltipText":"Serialized limited release, resellable.","CssTag":"limited-unique","LoadAssetRestrictionIconCss":true,"HasTooltip":false},"AssetStatusIcon":null,"Thumbnail":{"Final":true,"Url":"https://t7.rbxcdn.com/f6de30365dbad45c10685044d46bdffa","RetryUrl":"","IsApproved":true}},

for i in range(5):
    itm = t["Items"][i]["AssetId"]
        if not ListedItems.get(itm):
            if t["Items"][i]["AssetStatusIcon"]:
                ListedItems[t["Items"][i]["AssetId"]] = True
                msg = "@everyone\n\n-----New Item!-----\n" + t["Items"][i]["AbsoluteUrl"]
```

On the line where `itm = t["Items"][i]["AssetId"]` is where I get the error?
I'm not sure why since I'm fairly new to using python.

The error is

> list index out of range

Comment: what is inside itm?

Comment: t is a big json table that i've converted to a normal table

Comment: What is `t`?  The problem is happening because `t["Items"]` does not have 5 elements

Comment: verify your t first... it's incomplete, validate your json [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid `index out of range` error you can follow this method:

```
for itm in items:
    icon = itm.get('AssetStatusIcon', None)
    if icon:
        msg = "@everyone\n\n-----New Item!-----\n" + itm.get('AbsoluteUrl')
        print(msg)
```

Note: Your existing json structure is invalid, you need to load it first with `json.loads()` and before that validate your json structure at [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)